# How to do view inheritance in MVP?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I am designing a windows forms applications implementing MVP pattern, and here what i want to do.

I have a BaseView, which is actually a windows form. It has some elements, and all the other views in my application must inherit these elements. Now what i want to do, is to have some kind of limitation, such that each view that inherits my BaseView MUST have it's Presenter and it's interface. Here is what i've done so far.

Here are the interfaces:

```
public interface IView
{
}

public interface ISplashScreenView : IView
{
}
```

Here are the presenters:

```
public class BasePresenter 
{
    IView view;

    public BasePresenter(IView view) 
    {
        this.view = view;
    }
}

public class SplashScreenPresenter : Presenter
{
    public SplashScreenPresenter(IView view) : base(view)
    {
    }
}
```

And here is the BaseView(only .cs part)

```
public partial class EIBaseView : Form, IView
{
    public Presenter presenter;

    public EIBaseView(Presenter presenter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }
}
```

As you can see, i've created a parameterless constructor so each view inherited from it must give it's presenter as a parameter, but here is my problem.

```
public partial class SplashScreenView : EIBaseView, ISplashScreenView
{
    public SplashScreenView() : base(???)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to pass a presenter to my base class, because the presenter needs to get a reference to my view, but as the constructor is not called yet, how come can I pass my views 'this' to a presenter and pass it to the base constructor?

Maybe i'm going totally wrong way, but my goal is to create an inheritance that will force each view that will have my BaseView's attributes to create a Presenter, and implement a View.

Comment: Looks like you have a [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). One of the ways around this is to use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: You need to decide what part of the implementation will glue together the concrete view with its concrete presenter. You cannot have either of them constructed if they both insist on getting a reference to the other in their constructors.  You need to decide between the chicken and the egg :)

Comment: @user1620220 could you please bring a code example, because i didn't really get the point of using observer here.

Comment: @Biscuits yeah, but other way how can i force each view that inherits my BaseView implement the MVP pattern?)